# How can I have org-babel wrap my latex fragment in dollar signs before it is evaluated?

Tags: latex, org-babel, math, noweb

I find myself having to note equations fairly often, many of which reference each other. Therefore, I've used `noweb` to keep my notes DRY.

```
#+name: cost
#+begin_src latex
$J(\vec{w},b)$
#+end_src
```

[image: first equation]

My problem is that when I have to wrap one equation in dollar signs, any equation that references it ends up broken:

```
#+name: sq_er_cost
#+begin_src latex
$<<cost>> = \frac{1}{2m}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{m}(f_{w,b}(x)^{i} -y^{i})^{2}$
#+end_src
```

[image: equation naively wrapped]

I can work around this by being more specific about where I place my dollar signs:

```
#+name: sq_er_cost
#+begin_src latex
<<cost>> $= \frac{1}{2m}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{m}(f_{w,b}(x)^{i} -y^{i})^{2}$
#+end_src
```

[image: equation with sneakily wrapped parts]

Can anyone help me to teach org-mode/babel to do that wrapping for me? Then, I might rewrite the previous two blocks to not have to include the dollar signs at all:

```
#+name: cost
#+begin_src latex
J(\vec{w},b)
#+end_src

#+name: sq_er_cost
#+begin_src latex
<<cost>> = \frac{1}{2m}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{m}(f_{w,b}(x)^{i} -y^{i})^{2}
#+end_src
```

Comment: I tried the prologue, and epilogue, header arguments, but had no success.

Comment: It seems they may not yet be implemented for latex blocks.

https://list.orgmode.org/87a6r5u6lg.fsf@ucl.ac.uk/t/#u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are willing to fork your Org mode, you can redefine the function `org-babel-expand-body:latex` to take `:prologue` and `:epilogue` into account. It's an easy modification as shown below. Then, as you surmised, you can use `:prologue "\\ensuremath{` and `:epilogue "}"` to make sure that the results are properly set in a math environment.

The following file exports to PDF correctly for me:

```org
#+OPTIONS: toc:nil

* Exported Latex


Here's the first equation:

#+name: cost
#+begin_src latex :prologue "\\ensuremath{" :epilogue "}"
J(\vec{w},b)
#+end_src

My problem is that when I have to wrap one equation in dollar signs, any equation that references it ends up broken:

#+name: sq_er_cost
#+begin_src latex :noweb yes  :prologue "\\ensuremath{" :epilogue "}"
<<cost>> = \frac{1}{2m}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{m}(f_{w,b}(x)^{i} -y^{i})^{2}
#+end_src

* Code                                                             :noexport:

#+begin_src elisp
  (defun org-babel-expand-body:latex (body params)
    "Expand BODY according to PARAMS, return the expanded body."
    (mapc (lambda (pair) ;; replace variables
            (setq body
                  (replace-regexp-in-string
                   (regexp-quote (format "%S" (car pair)))
                   (if (stringp (cdr pair))
                       (cdr pair) (format "%S" (cdr pair)))
                   body)))
          (org-babel--get-vars params))
    (let ((pro (cdr (assq :prologue params)))
          (epi (cdr (assq :epilogue params))))
      (concat pro (org-trim body) epi)))

#+end_src
```

Just do `C-c C-c` on the code block to redefine the function and then export normally with `C-c C-e l o`. You can get rid of the modification by restarting emacs or by doing `M-x load-library ob-latex`. If you want the redefinition permanently, then add it to your init file under an `eval-after-load`:

```el
(eval-after-load 'ob-latex
  (defun org-babel-expand-body:latex (body params)
    ...))
```

The only change to the function is that we retrieve the values of the `:prologue` and `:epilogue` headers and we wrap them around the (trimmed) body.

I'll try posting the modification to Org mode and see if they accept it. If so, I'll update the answer with the details.

Comment: I hope they accept the change! I've spent some time trying to figure out how to do exactly this, but had no idea where to start, so thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Confirming: this works like a charm!